# Ruby read 2 integers at the same time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two integers on a line in `STDIN` which I would like to read at the same time.
I tried pattern matching like this:

```
[a, b] = gets.split.map(&:to_i)
```

However, this failed:

```
solution.rb:7: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting keyword_end
    [a, b] = gets.split.map(&:to_i)
```

How can I read two integers from the same line(preferably but not necessarily at the same time)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to remove brackets on the left side:

```
a, b = gets.split.map(&:to_i)
```

Answer (score 2):

It's better to be a safe side by using splat operator

```
a, b, * = gets.split.map(&:to_i)
```

for more info about splat operator, I've written a blog on [Ruby Splat operator](http://vgvinay2.github.io/programming/2015/01/28/ruby-splat.html)